# How to get the current path, including GET params, but without the framework params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an orders page. This orders page has a variety of optional filters, so at any given time, the user may be at a path like so:

```
/orders?from_date=05/01/2013&status=3
```

This page has a button on it that exports whatever the user is viewing as CSV. When I click this button, I want to hit the exact same URL, just with a format of CSV. So what I'm looking for in the above example is:

```
/orders.csv?from_date=05/01/2013&status=3
```

First attempt:

```
<%= link_to 'Export as CSV', current_url(:format => :csv) %>
=> /orders.csv?from_date=05/01/2013&status=3&action=show&controller=orders&subdomain=www
```

This includes my params, but it includes a bunch of framework params, too!

Second attempt:

```
<%= link_to 'Export as CSV', url_for(:format => :csv) %>
=> /orders.csv
```

OK... That removed ALL the parameters.

Am I missing an easy way to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more researching, I've found this solution:

```
<%= link_to 'Export to CSV', url_for(params.merge(:format => :csv)) %>

=> /orders.csv?from_date=05/01/2013&status=3
```

The `params` hash contains all parameters, including the ones I don't want, but `url_for` correctly strips out the parameters that are covered by routes.

Answer (score 1):

```
=link_to 'Export as CSV', 
url_for({format: :csv}.merge(params.except(:action, :controller, :subdomain))
```

Comment: Fair enough... Although in my actual case, this URL can be nested fairly deeply (for example, `/companies/14/teams/37/orders`) - which means a bunch of other `_id` fields are in the params list as well. Ideally I could somehow exclude all parameters that are part of the route, without having to list them all.

Comment: @ElliotNelson so maybe try whitelisting allowed params instead?